# Who are Veeras? Does a devotee after death becomes a Veera?

Tags: puranas, gods, death, bhakti

Veeras are described in the Tantrik scriptures as the souls who have attained special blessings from the Deity they chant name of. Does it mean a devotee after death becomes a Veera?
There are many Veeras like Naharsimha Veer, Hanuman Veer, Kalua Veer and others. In Tantrik texts related to Naath Pantha there are numerous ways to master these Veeras and get different tasks done by them. Are such astral entities like Veeras ever mentioned in Vedas and Puranas ? If yes then are they good souls or bad ones? Do they belong to army of deities?